# Does the free EaseUS partition master no longer support making a bootable USB?

Tags: easeus-partition-manager

Does the free EaseUS partition master no longer support making a bootable USB?

I used to use EaseUS partition master, free software and I think it offered an option to make a bootable USB version of itself otherwise I doubt i'd have used it.

Now though I download it and it has an option to make a WinPE thing but it says only in the pro version.

Is the option to make a bootable version no longer free?

i.e. is it that previously the bootable version was free, but no longer / have there been a policy change / them making their policy tighter on this?

Comment: Closing this because it is extremely limited in scope, not beneficial long-term in contributing knowledge to the network. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I used to use EaseUS partition master, free software and I think it offered an option to make a bootable USB version of itself otherwise I doubt I'd have used it.

Based on EaseUS website it was never possible to create a bootable media with the free edition of their software.

> Does the free EaseUS partition master no longer support making a bootable USB?

It never supported it.

> Is the option to make a bootable version no longer free?

The ability to create a WinPE bootable disk is not a feature of the free edition of the EaseUS partition manager.

[image]

> is it that previously the bootable version was free, but no longer

I look as far back as 2016 and it wasn't a feature then either.

[image]

I looked even further to 2015 and it still wasn't a feature.

[image]

In 2014 it was also not a feature of the free edition.

[image]

In 2013 the feature didn't even exist.

[image]

Source: [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/we)

> is it that previously the bootable version was free, but no longer / have there been a policy change / them making their policy tighter on this?

Based on historical evidence it was actually never a feature of the free edition.

Answer (score 0):

It did used to support it

https://web.archive.org/web/20121117091051/http://www.easeus.com/partition-recovery

[image]

It might have been at that time it was possible to run the **regular** easeus from within BartPE, BartPE was I think like a basic windows OS based on WinPE.

There is no WinPE option in the free one now. And maybe the regular version wouldn't even run within a BartPE / WinPE based OS.  It might be possible to do it but there's no option viewable to do it.

Comment: BartPE was based on WinPE which was customized.  It was based on the Windows XP version of WinPE.  WinPE can be customized and nearly any application can be added to a WinPE image.

Comment: AT Ramhound that makes sense, and in which case, probably one may as well run the regular version of whatever partition program and the lack of a slimmed down bootable usb version doesn't matter 'cos a fully/ regular  featured version can run off USB anyway. Though maybe arguably a tad less convenient